# Error creating table with foregin key constraint referencing multiple columns from same table: Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, rdbms, unique-constraint

I am creating tables in following steps-

```
create table student(rollno varchar(8) primary key, 
                     name varchar not null, 
                     admitted_on date, 
                     created_at timestamptz, 
                     department_id numeric 
                       references department(deptid));

-- select * from student;
```

```
alter table student 
  add constraint adhaar_constraint unique(adhaar_no);
```

Now, on executing following command-

```
create table student_address (
            address_id numeric,
            address1 varchar,
            address2 varchar,
            address3 varchar,
            city varchar,
            country varchar,
            student_id varchar, student_adhaar numeric, 
            foreign key(student_id,student_adhaar) references 
            student(rollno,adhaar_no),
            check (country not in ('Pakistan','Afghanistan','Turkey'
)))
```

I get error-

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint 
matching given keys for referenced table "student"
SQL state: 42830
```

Can somebody please explain the reason? I am trying to include multiple columns in a single foregin key.

Comment: Your primary key is rollno, not rollno,adhaar_no

Comment: Two single column unique constraints doesn't form a single two-column unique constraint. You should declare it explicitly if you want to reference it as a composite key.